# ListView representing data being changed frequently on non-UI thread - library API design

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a scenario where a `ListView` needs to represent an array of data that could be modified at any time on a non-UI thread.

I'm already aware of the techniques to ensure that the `Adapter`'s backing data is not modified concurrently by a non-UI thread while the `ListView` is redrawing itself through the `Adapter`. Essentially, the techniques all boil down to ensuring the `Adapter` has its own copy of the data which is only touched on the UI thread. Various options such as `runOnUiThread()` or `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExcecute()` provide means of ensuring the UI thread 'copy' is only modified on the UI thread.

My question is more of a design issue. My application concerns representation of data being collected from a hardware device via TCP socket connection. I wish to represent that hardware device as a library, so that observing and accessing data from it is all done through a set of API methods. The device would be represented as an object, and the object represents a local cache of the device's state. Within the library, data will be changed in response to socket `read()` calls on the socket read thread. Because the library needs to be used in a desktop PC application, I'm unable to use Android framework components within it to cause data changes to happen on the UI thread. Therefore, when the library obtains new data from the hardware, data changes and subsequent observer callbacks would happen on non-UI thread.

What would be an elegant way to let the Android application maintain a UI-thread-safe direct view on the data within the library without needing to maintain (shallow) copies of all the data within the application?

One idea I have so far is to design the library such that it gives the user application the option to "intercept" TCP message processing so that it can be made to happen on the UI thread. For example, the Android app might use the library like this:

```
// HardwareDevice is my library - an abstracty representation of 
// networked hardware box that spits out lots of state data.

HardwareDevice mDevice = new HardwareDevice(); // Create abstraction of the device

// As standard, the library will do its JSON message parsing and 
// subsequent data modifications on the socket read thread. 
// This is an optional way to change intercept that behaviour so that the
// processing happens on the UI thread.
mDevice.setMessagePreprocessor(new MessagePreprocessor(){
    void processMessage(String message){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mDevice.processMessage(message);
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Not tested code so there may be syntax errors, but the point is this: It's a way of making the library perform its callbacks and data changes on the Android UI thread when used within an Android application, without having to make the library itself Android-specific. This, from what I can see, would make the rest of the application far easier to create by minimizing synchronization/copying that has to happen to significant amounts of data.

In other words, from this point on, I could very safely grab lists of data like this:

```
mDevice.getArrayListOfStuff()
```

...and safely use that to directly back an `Adapter` even though the underlying data is subject to frequent asynchronous change.

Is this a good strategy? Have I missed a more obvious option?

Comment: Do you know how to manipulate the ArrayList in a non UI-Thread?